# Warning: Illegal string offset INSERT INTO

Tags: php

I used explode to get the first name and the last one informed in an input, and join them with a dot in the middle, at the moment when the user is registering on my site.
Example: John Wesley Marques
Expected result with Explode = John.Marques

And then I want to insert this information in the database, but only the insertion in the DB is not working, it presents the following error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'user_login' in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \
>   Login-system \ register.php on line 24

Could you help me with that?

I'm putting my code here.

```
<?php

session_start();

//Limpar memória
ob_start();

//Verificar o valor do botão
$btnRegister = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'btnRegister', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//Incluir no Banco de dados
if($btnRegister) {
    include_once 'connection.php';

    //Receber o valor dos outros campos
    $data = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

    //Explode
    $login_user ="'". $data['user_nicename'] ."'";
    $login_user_new = explode(" ", $login_user);
    $new_login_user = $login_user_new[0] .".". $login_user_new[count($login_user_new)-1];

    //Inserir o resultado do Explode no Data Base
    $user_login = "INSERT INTO tinvest_users (user_login) VALUE ('" .$new_login_user['user_login']. "')";
    $res_user_login = mysqli_query($conn, $user_login);

    //Visualizar o conteúdo das variáveis
    /*var_dump($new_login_user);
    var_dump($data);*/

    //Criptografar a senha
    $data['user_pass'] = password_hash($data['user_pass'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    //Inserir no banco de Dados
    $result_user = "INSERT INTO tinvest_users (user_pass, user_nicename, user_email) VALUES (
        '".$data['user_pass']."',
        '".$data['user_nicename']."',
        '".$data['user_email']."'
    )";

    //executar a query acima
    $res_user = mysqli_query($conn, $result_user);
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Cadastre-se Titanium Investimentos</title>

</head>
<body>

    <h2>Cadastre-se<h2>
    <h3><h3>

<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['msg'];
    unset($_SESSION['msg']);
}
?>
    <form method="POST" action = "">

            <!--Usúario-->
            <input type="text" name="user_nicename" placeholder="Digite seu nome completo" autofocus><br><br>

            <!--Email-->
            <input type="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail"><br><br>

            <!--Senha-->
            <input type="password" name="user_pass" placeholder="Digite sua senha"><br><br>

            <!--Botão-->
            <input type="submit" name="btnRegister" value="Cadastrar">

            <!--Link Cadastrar-->
            <h4>Não possui conta ainda?</h4>
            <a href="login.php">Fazer Login</a>

    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$new_login_user` can only be a string so you can't use string indexes like `'user_login'`

Answer (score 0):

`$new_login_user` is not an array. It a string value so you can't call like array `$new_login_user['user_login']`. You just call it as string `$new_login_user`.